# lift a value into a ValidationNel

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given a value and a predicate, how to create a `ValidationNel` ?

Here is my code :

```
def toValidationNel[A, E](a: A)(f: A => Boolean, fail: => E) : ValidationNel[E, A] =
  if (f(a)) fail.failureNel[A] else a.successNel[E]
```

Is there an existing combinator in scalaz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalaz includes an `either` extension method for booleans that's similar to `Either.cond` but arguably a little nicer:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def toValNel[A, E](a: A)(f: A => Boolean, fail: => E) : ValidationNel[E, A] =
  f(a).either(a).or(fail.wrapNel).validation
```

I've never really liked the fact that the right side for `Either.cond` comes on the left, and Scalaz's version makes the either-or-ness a little clearer to my eye, but it's also potentially harder for people who aren't familiar with Scalaz to understand at a glance. I don't see any strong reason to prefer one over the other, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Either.cond`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either$@cond[A,B]%28test:Boolean,right:=%3EB,left:=%3EA%29:scala.util.Either[A,B]) from `scala.util.Either` :

```
import scalaz.ValidationNel
import scalaz.syntax.std.either._
import scalaz.syntax.nel._

def toValidationNel[A, E](a: A)(f: A => Boolean, fail: => E) : ValidationNel[E, A] =
  Either.cond(f(a), a, fail.wrapNel).validation
```